# ArcPy convert raster TIFF to PNG

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, python-2.7, error-999999

ArcGIS 10.2 and I use ArcPy and I have create a ArcPy script. I want my final raster from script to create two raster datasets with different extensions, a TIFF extension and a PNG extension.

Here is the code:

```
minvalue = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(final, "MINIMUM")
minvalue2 = (minvalue.getOutput(0))
maxvalue = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(final, "MAXIMUM")
maxvalue2 = (maxvalue.getOutput(0))
# Process: Reclassify (6)
arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(final, "VALUE","{0} 6 1;7 32 2;33 162 3;163 512 4;513 1250 5;1250 {1} 6".format(minvalue2, maxvalue2), final1,"DATA")
try:
    arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion (final1,"OtherFormat", {"PNG"})
except:
    print "Raster To Other Format exsample failed."
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

message:

```
Raster To Other Format exsample failed.
Executing: Reclassify in_memory/final VALUE "0 6 1;7 32 2;33 162 3;163 512 4;513 1250 5;1250 39370526556160 6" C:\Users\username\Desktop\myimage.tif DATA
Start Time: Wed Feb 28 23:10:44 2018
Succeeded at Wed Feb 28 23:10:46 2018 (Elapsed Time: 2,03 seconds)
```

Here is the second test for the conversion:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('C:/Users/username/Desktop/test.tif')
new_im = im.convert('RGBA')
new_im.save('test.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=100)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/test/newt.py", line 5, in <module>
    new_im = im.convert('RGBA')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 857, in convert
    self.load()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1011, in load
    return super(TiffImageFile, self).load()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 204, in load
    decoder.setimage(self.im, extents)
ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

Third test:

```
try:
    arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion(final1,"OtherFormat","PNG")
except:
    print "Raster To Other Format exsample failed."
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

message :

```
Raster To Other Format exsample failed.
Executing: RasterToOtherFormat C:/Users/username/myimage.tif OtherFormat PNG
Start Time: Wed Feb 28 23:24:34 2018
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Output Workspace: Dataset OtherFormat does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (RasterToOtherFormat).
Failed at Wed Feb 28 23:24:34 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0,00 seconds)
```

final test:

```
arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(final, "VALUE","{0} 6 1;7 32 2;33 162 3;163 512 4;513 1250 5;1250 {1} 6".format(minvalue2, maxvalue2), final1,"DATA")
try:
    out_rasterdataset='test.png'
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(final1, out_rasterdataset)
except:
    print "Raster To Other Format exsample failed."
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

message:

```
Raster To Other Format exsample failed.
Executing: CopyRaster C:/Users/username/myimage.tif test.tif # # 1 NONE NONE # NONE NONE
Start Time: Wed Feb 28 23:35:49 2018
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (CopyRaster).
Failed at Wed Feb 28 23:35:49 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0,03 seconds)
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion (final1,"OtherFormat", {"PNG"})? isn't right. The args are Input_Rasters, Output_Workspace, {Raster_Format}, Final1 is right but the 2nd argument is the **folder you want the raster to end up in** and the 3rd argument **isn't a dictionary** so it's just "PNG", the parenthesis in the docs is just telling you that the argument is **optional** not to put parenthesis around the argument.

Answer (score 3):

From ArcGIS 10 there are new [objects for rasters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000051000000), you are using the old (9.3) methods but you will find better functionality with the new objects.

Most of your trouble comes from not specifying exactly *where* to put your raster and from misunderstanding the help.. when the help puts parenthesis around a parameter it means *optional* not *put a parenthesis around your parameter*, that would make `{"PNG"}` a dictionary with a key but no value..

Try this:

```
import os
OutputWorkspace = r'c:\some\path' # where you want to put the files output
OutputTIFF      = "Output.tif"    # the name of the TIFF file
OutputPNG       = "Output.png"    # the name of the PNG file

minvalue = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(final, "MINIMUM")
minvalue2 = float(minvalue.getOutput(0)) # make sure minimum is numeric
maxvalue = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(final, "MAXIMUM")
maxvalue2 = float(maxvalue.getOutput(0)) # make sure maximum is numeric
# Process: Reclassify (6)
# make a RemapRange 
Remap = arcpy.sa.RemapRange([[minvalue2,6,1],[7,32,2],[33,162,3],[163,512,4],[513,1250,5],[1250,maxvalue2,6]])
# reclassify the raster to a new raster 
ReclassRaster = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(final,"VALUE",Remap,"DATA")
# ReclassRaser is now a raster object 
ReclassRaster.save(os.path.join(OutputWorkspace,OutputTIFF))
ReclassRaster.save(os.path.join(OutputWorkspace,OutputPNG))
```

The newer help for [Reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) uses a [RemapRange](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005m0000007m000000) object which is a list of lists rather than a semicolon and space delimited string, this produces a raster that has a `.save` method but be sure to be specific about your output location; if not specified your current workspace could be `None` which is why you're having trouble saving the file, either set `arcpy.env.workspace` or specify the **full path in your filesystem to store the output raster**.

Comment: i try to test your code but i get some error again,only with GDAL transate i can to convert that images,but i wanto to do using arcpy

Comment: What error? What does you current code look like? Can you edit your question to include the code as it is currently and the text of the error message. I can see a syntax error which I will fix up now.